# Как присвоить значение id другой колонке Laravel, Eloquent, Migrations

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, миграция

Есть колонка id типа bigIncrements, нужно создать вторую колонку position и присвоить ей значение id. Не понимаю как перехватить значение id при создании нового объекта, а присвоить position нужно именно при создании объекта...

Comment: Создали объект, установили значение.

Comment: Можно с помощью средств базы данных - [триггерами](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: @Alpha         Как я не додумался... Автоматизирован должен быть процесс)